# How to alias IDs in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table in my DynamoDB

| PK | SK | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user#aee97067-b363-495c-9531-f1da15812eee | user#aee97067-b363-495c-9531-f1da15812eee | John |

I also have a user profile feature in my web application. Users can navigate to their profiles using a URL like http://example.com/aee97067-b363-495c-9531-f1da15812eee. However, I find the long ID in the URL cumbersome, so I want to allow users to create aliases for their IDs. This way, instead of using the UUID, they can use a more human-readable alias in the URL, such as http://example.com/johndoe

How should the DynamoDB be structured in order to support this?

I have two solutions for how to do this, but I'm not sure which to choose because each has its own drawbacks

1. Replace original UUID in PK with an alias

| PK | SK | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user#johndoe | user#johndoe | John |

2. Create a GSI (Global Secondary Index) for the alias and query by the GSI.

| PK | SK | name | GSI1PK | GSI1SK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user#aee97067-b363-495c-9531-f1da15812eee | user#aee97067-b363-495c-9531-f1da15812eee | John | user#johndoe | user#aee97067-b363-495c-9531-f1da15812eee |

In the first approach, I'm uncertain if it's a good idea to modify the "static" ID, because it might be used in logs and for "relational" references with other items.

In the second approach, there is no issue with editing its ID because it's a regular attribute. This method works well for querying data, but whenever I need to insert data, I have to somehow remap an alias to the ID. I'm not sure if it's efficient to request the "real" user ID by its alias on each write request in the controller before performing the write operation.

Can you suggest which approach I should use and why? Perhaps you have some experience with this and can share it with me

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use option 2 - make a GSI keyed by alias.

A human-readable alias like "johndoe" is something could have a reason to change.  It's also reasonable to expect that you might someday have users with multiple aliases or no alias.

You shouldn't use something like that a primary key in any kind of database, because when/if it *does* change, it will break all of the references to the user in all of your systems.

It's important to ensure that primary keys have no purpose other than to identify the things they identify.

Comment: In the case of Option 2, how can I insert data into the table? I need to know the primary key (PK) of the main table in order to write to it. On the UI, I can only use an alias in a URL, for example, http://example.com/<ALIAS>

Comment: You should look the alias in the GSI to get the primary key.  Do this early -- in all your internal APIs and other databases, you should identify users by ID, not alias.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question mostly depends on your specific requirements. Here is my input to help you decide:

#### Option 1

1. Allows you to easily update/write items without fetching first
2. Ensures there are no duplicate aliases
3. Is good for high write throughput use-cases, especially if you don't use the long-id for other things.
4. Modifying the alias would require a Delete/Put

#### Option 2

1. If your use-case is read dominant and you still have a valid requirement to read using the long-id then this is a good option.
2. High write throughput would also cause you to read first, which is relatively inexpensive in comparison, but would increase your latency slightly. It would also introduce race conditions requiring you to implement optimistic locking.

#### Option 3

Have option 1 as you base table, allowing you to write items based on alias. And the long-id as GSI index key, allowing you to read using long-id when/if required.

Comment: I also like Option 1 because it simplifies everything. The only question I have is, if I need to do a Delete/Put, does it mean that my page will be unavailable for the short period while it's being deleted?

Comment: Your page will change alias, so you will have to force a refresh. Something like a spinning wheel when the edit is being persisted, and sleep for 1-2 seconds, fetch the new wep-page and then it'll just look as if the update completed.